# Get Create as Select Table History Statement

Tags: postgresql, ddl, information-schema

Postgres 12

table created as select from other table(s)

```
create table t1
as
select t2.col1, t3.col2
from t2
join t3 on t2.colx=t3.coly
where t2.col4='XYZ';
```

if table was created with above 'create as select' statement, is there any possibility that i can get above 'create as select' statement from the table 't1' definition or from somewhere else like 'information schema' etc?

Comment: No the query is not stored anywhere. If you want that, use a materialized view

Comment: Tables don't store that, but you can generate such a statement using [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to construct it based on the information in `information_schema.columns`. You could also save that `create` statement as a table comment [`COMMENT ON TABLE t1 IS 'your query here'`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html) and then read it with [`SELECT obj_description('t1'::regclass::oid)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-COMMENT-TABLE)